# Rendering to CAMetalLayer from dedicated render thread / loop

Tags: macos, cocoa, metal, metalkit

In Windows World, a dedicated render thread would loop something similar to this:

```
void RenderThread()
{
    while (!quit)
    {
        UpdateStates();
        RenderToDirect3D();
        // Can either present with no synchronisation,
        // or synchronise after 1-4 vertical blanks.
        // See docs for IDXGISwapChain::Present
        PresentToSwapChain();
    }
}
```

What is the equivalent in Cocoa with `CAMetalLayer`? All the examples deal with updates being done in the main thread, either using `MTKView` (with it's internal timer) or using `CADisplayLink` in the iOS examples.

I want to be in control of the whole render loop, rather than just receiving a callback at some non-specified interval (and ideally blocking for V-Sync if it's enabled).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At some level, you're going to be throttled by the availability of drawables. A `CAMetalLayer` has a fixed pool of drawables available, and calling `nextDrawable` will block the current thread until a drawable becomes available. This doesn't imply you have to call `nextDrawable` at the top of your render loop, though.

If you want to draw on your own schedule without getting blocked waiting on a drawable, render to an off-screen renderbuffer (i.e., a `MTLTexture` with dimensions matching your drawable size), and then blit from the most-recently-drawn texture to a drawable's texture and present on whatever cadence you prefer. This can be useful for getting frame timings, but every frame you draw and then don't display is wasted work. It also increases the risk of judder.

Your options are limited when it comes to getting callbacks that match the v-sync cadence. Your best is almost certainly a `CVDisplayLink` scheduled in the default and tracking run loop modes, though this has [caveats](http://thume.ca/2017/12/09/cvdisplaylink-doesnt-link-to-your-display/).

You could use something like a counting semaphore in concert with a display link if you want to free-run without getting too far ahead.

If your application is able to maintain a real-time framerate, you'll normally be rendering a frame or two ahead of what's going on the glass, so you don't want to literally block on v-sync; you just want to inform the window server that you'd like presentation to match v-sync. On macOS, you do this by setting the layer's `displaySyncEnabled` to true (the default). Turning this off may cause tearing on certain displays.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've tweaked the question to make it clear that Direct3D doesn't always sync after a single frame.

Answer (score 2):

At the point where you want to render to screen, you obtain the drawable from the layer by calling `nextDrawable`. You obtain the drawable's texture from its `texture` property. You use that texture to set up the render target (color attachment) of a `MTLRenderPassDescriptor`. For example:

```
id<CAMetalDrawable> drawable = layer.nextDrawable;
id<MTLTexture> texture = drawable.texture;
MTLRenderPassDescriptor *desc = [MTLRenderPassDescriptor renderPassDescriptor];
desc.colorAttachments[0].texture = texture;
```

From here, it's pretty similar to what you do in an `MTKView`'s `drawRect:` method. You create a command buffer (if you don't already have one), create a render command encoder using the descriptor, encode drawing commands, end encoding, tell the command buffer to present the drawable (using a `-presentDrawable:...` method), and commit the command buffer. Whatever was drawn to the drawable's texture is what will end up on-screen when it's presented.

I agree with Warren that you probably don't really want to sync your loop with the display refresh. You want parallelism. You want the CPU to be working on the next frame while the GPU is rendering the most current frame (and the display is showing the last frame).

The fact that there's a limit on how many drawables may be in flight at once and that `nextDrawable` will block waiting for one will prevent your render loop from getting too far ahead. (You'll probably use some other synchronization before that, like for managing a small pool of buffers.) If you want only double-buffering and not triple-buffering, you can set the layer's `maximumDrawableCount` to 2 instead of its default value of 3.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've tweaked the question to make it clear that Direct3D doesn't always sync after a single frame.